# Error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" what is wrong here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input ("What is your name?")
quest = input("What is your quest?")
color = input ("what is your favorite color")

print ("Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is{}, and your favorite color is{}.")str.format(name, quest, color)
```

Comment: Why are you call str.format? Just use yourstring.format(...

Comment: The format method would be called *on the `"Ah, so ... is{}."` string*. Not on the `str` type.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error starting at `str.format...` so it can't have the error you claim. Please test your code and post a demonstration that produces the error. Its likely some silly thing but we are blocked with a different silly thing.

Answer (score 1):

`.format()` is a method on strings. You need to call it on your template string:

```
print("Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is{}, and your favorite color is{}.".format(name, quest, color))
```

Note how the `.format()` follows directly after the `"Ah, so ... is{}."` string definition, and the *result* of that method is passed to the `print(...)` function for printing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give argument numbers to `.format`. try below.

print ("Ah, so your name is {0}, your quest is {1}, and your favorite color is {2}.".format(name, quest, color))